# Finding $g(N)$ for $T(N)= \frac{\exp(N^3)}{\lg N}$ such that $T(N) = \Theta(g(N))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, solution-verification

Could a correct answer be $$g(n)=\frac{N\exp(N^3)}{N\lg N}$$ for $T(N)=\Theta(g(N))$ if $T(N)= \frac{\exp(N^3)}{\lg N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this will work, it's the same function. Another one is a different way to write it, note that $\log N = e^{\log \log N}$, so
$$
\frac{\exp\left(N^3\right)}{\exp(\log \log N)}
 = \exp\left(N^3 - \log \log N\right)
$$

You can scale by any constant and add any lower order terms, for example
$$
25 \pi\exp\left(N^3 - \log \log N\right) + N^{100} e^N
$$
will do fine as well.